# Expanding on where put put a critical section when dealing with loader threads and large amount of data

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I've read tutorials on the subject and watched YouTube videos on it and I think I understand the reasoning behind why they are used. There are a lot of reasons why they are used, but one of the is because modern multi-core CPU's have internal caches to increase performance (L1 and L2). This might result in one core reading old information if they have old memory stored in the cache associated with that core. Adding critical sections forces those caches to be refreshed.

I'm trying to increase my understanding on where this critical section has to be put, which I feel most online information sources actually fail to explain well. That's why I'm asking the you pros here! :)

Let be give you a short example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <list>

static constexpr auto OneMegabyte = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

struct Result
{
    char data[OneMegabyte];
};

std::mutex mutex;
std::list<Result*> results;

void write_lots_of_data(Result* result)
{
    auto f = fopen("large_file.txt", "rb");
    fread(result->data, OneMegabyte, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
}

void read_lots_of_data(Result* result)
{
    //
}

void thread()
{
    auto result = new Result();
    // Writes one megabyte of data from somewhere into Memory::values
    write_lots_of_data(result);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mutex);
    results.push_back(result);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::thread t(&thread);
    while (true)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mutex);
        if (results.empty())
            continue;

        auto first_result = results.begin();
        read_lots_of_data(*first_result);
        results.erase(first_result);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Access to `results` is protected from being read and written at the same time - this I understand. But what about the actual memory put into the `results` list? Do I have to put the critical section before the `write_lots_of_data` method to be safe or is it enough to safely protect the `results` list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct.

The mutex is guarding the list and not the data contained withing the list node. Therefore, as you have written, the filling of the data into the Result struct is unprotected and does not need protection.

When reading, only the list needs protection. The reading of the results do not need protection. Your code should work as written. It can be improved in one way:

```
Result* get_result()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mutex);
    if (not results.empty())
    {
        Result* first_result = results.front();
        results.pop_front();
        return first_result;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::thread t(&thread);
    while (true)
    {
        Result* first_result = get_result();
        if (first_result)
        {
            read_lots_of_data(first_result);
            delete first_result;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Limiting the lock to operate only on the list would help both performance and readability. The reader will realize that only the list is being locked and not the reading operation of the result.

Before you go too far, consider using `std::unique_ptr<Result>` as well in your code rather than new/delete.